# How to update docker-machine on Linux?

Tags: software-installation, docker

I installed docker-machine on my Ubuntu 18.04 with the instruction provided in [Install Docker Machine](https://docs.docker.com/v17.12/machine/install-machine/#install-machine-directly). Now how do I update it to a more recent version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I found out, it is enough to just rerun the commands for installation with changed version in the link

For example, this command installs version 0.14.0:

```
curl -L https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.14.0/docker-machine-uname -s`-`uname -m` >/tmp/docker-machine && \
sudo install /tmp/docker-machine /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
```

If you want to update it to 0.16.0, you just run:

```
curl -L https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.16.0/docker-machine-`uname -s`-`uname -m` >/tmp/docker-machine && \
sudo install /tmp/docker-machine /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
```